# Invalid hook call on react router useHistory

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm aware some changes was made with react router library in the new version, though I think I followed the changes correctly and still receiving the following error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Here is my code

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
function Home() {
    const history = useHistory(); //This hook causing the error
    const RouteAbout = () => {
      history.push("/about");
    }
    return(<> 
       <button onClick={RouteAbout}> test </button>
    </>);
}
```

The error refers to

`const history = useHistory();`

that imported from

`import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';`

How can I apply `useHistory` hook with react router in a valid way?

EDIT:

App.JS

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/portfolio">
            <Portfolio />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/contact">
            <Contact />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    <Footer/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Versions

```
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-perf-devtool": "^3.1.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
```

Comment: try this onClick = { () => history.push("/about")  }

Comment: which version of react and react-dom are you using?

Comment: @Emanuele `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"` and `"react": "^16.14.0"` also `"history": "^4.10.1"`

Comment: You have a typo: "retrun" should be "return", and it should not be called like a function.

Comment: @backtick updated it in my question, but the error is points at `let history` as the issue here. the return is written correctly in my real code (it's longer and irrelevant to the question)

Comment: OK. Also, see Emanuele's question. They're asking which version of `react-dom` you're using, not `react-router-dom`. If the versions of `react-dom` and `react` don't match, this error can occur.

Comment: @backtick `"react-dom": "^17.0.2"`, Maybe I need to update react?

Comment: @backtick updated react, and react-dom, nothing changed. by searching online it's pretty common issue, but no solution so far helped me.

Comment: We'll find it. :) Can you include in your example where you are using the `Home` component?

Comment: @backtick updated my question. The route is working fine, only useHistory is failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231707/discussion-between-backtick-and-yotam-dahan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't found what causing this error, but found an alternative.

Using `NavLink` although the conflict of link & button as HTML tags worked for me.
A good solution will be to remove the `<button>` tag and "fake" one using `<a>` tag which provided by `NavLink`.

```
<NavLink to="/about" onClick={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}><button>test</button></NavLink>
```

or

```
<NavLink to="/about" onClick={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>test</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure to have wrapped your application inside a `BrowserRouter`?

This code works for me.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import { useHistory, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  let history = useHistory();
  const RouteAbout = () => {
    history.push("/about");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={RouteAbout}> test </button>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Yes I wrapped it with `Browser Router`. Though my problem is using `let history = useHistory();`, for some reason it throws an error.